# RuntimeError: Java not found

Tags: stanford-nlp

I hava download JDK&deploy the `Java_HOME` and so on,i can use "javac" in Command,but when i use it like

`nlp=StanfordCoreNLP(r'stanfordnlp',lang='zh')`

there has a problem:

> builtins.RuntimeError: Java not found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run out of memory. According to my experience, shutting down Java and restarting it can solve this issue.